# Java AWT Native Frame Color incorrect in Windows XP

Tags: java, windows-xp, awt, background-color

I'm developing a GUI for a moderately complex application using Java AWT for the GUI and it looks great when I run it in X11 (with any desktop manager) on linux but in Windows XP it looks weird.

Actually, at first it looks okay but if I need to change the background color of any of the frames, I can't change it back to the correct color afterwards. When I try to set the background color back to normal the frames get what looks like solid white backgrounds rather than the beige color that native applications have in XP. I can't seem to make them look more natural.

I've tried:

```
frame.setBackground(null);
```

and

```
frame.setBackground(java.awt.SystemColor.window);
```

with no success. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help!

-Jonathan Perry-Houts

Edit: Here's a quick example to demonstrate what I mean, I would expect this small empty frame to be beige but instead it's white in Windows XP:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame f = new Frame("Hello World");
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        f.setBackground(SystemColor.window);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, never knew about `SystemColor`. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @jmp: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: @jmp: Have you tried `SystemColor.control`?

Comment: @veer: Thanks! SystemColor.control looks like the color I was looking for. I wouldn't have expected that but it definitely looks correct. And it's the same color as SystemColor.window in LXDE so that explains why I wasn't seeing the same problem in linux.

Comment: @Jeffrey it's java 1.6.0 but as veer stated in his answer, I guess that's not necessarily the best way to do it if you're trying to be cross-platform compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045224/java-awt-native-frame-color-incorrect-in-windows-xp#comment16082378_12045224)... have you tried `SystemColor.control`? It should work! Be wary, however, when using `SystemColor`... it is a relic from a time when Motif and Windows 95-98 UI were predominantly used. More often than not, it will be utterly inadequate for dealing with modern UIs.

Comment: Thanks! This program is just some lab software that will probably never be used on another computer so in this case it's okay that it might not look as nice elsewhere, thanks for the help!